# Canonical topology on the set of functors between topological categories?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

Let $C, D$ be topological categroies. Ist there a canonical topology on the set of functors $Fun(C,D)$? Thank you

Comment: I have never heard of something like this before.  Would you maybe be able to motivate the question by explaining why there should be such a topology?

Comment: I am looking at simplicial sets and spaces which can be defined in two ways: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_set. If I use the definition via a contravariant functor and look at the nerv https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_(category_theory) of a topological category, I want to get a simplicial space using the definition using the functor definition

Comment: See Brown, Ronald; Nickolas, Peter 
Exponential laws for topological categories, groupoids and groups, and mapping spaces of colimits. Cahiers de Topologie et Géométrie Différentielle Catégoriques, 20 no. 2 (1979), p. 179-198   http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CTGDC_1979__20_2_179_0

Answer (score 2):

I assume that, by topological category, you mean a category enriched in topological spaces. 
Generically, what you expect is that the category of *topological* functors, or continuous functors, is itself naturally a topological category. This works with a complete and cocomplete symmetric monoidal closed category of spaces, of which there are various popular examples such as the weakly Hausdorff compactly generated spaces. So there is a space of natural transformations between two topological functors, but the functors themselves do not form a space, other than trivially. (You certainly can't do this with arbitrary functors, since these ignore the topological information.)

What you need for a space of functors is a space of objects in your "topological categories," where now you must switch to talking about categories internal to the category of spaces; in this case, internal category theory becomes a generalization of enriched category theory. The question of exponentials among internal categories is somewhat more subtle-one approach is in the paper Ronnie linked.